# Runtime error for a reason I can't figure out

Tags: java, arraylist

This code is supposed to take 2 integer array lists of length 3 such as (3, 3, 4) and (1, 2, 3), compare each index, and find which one is greater.

It then awards a point to whichever is greater, so 3>1 means array list 1 gets a point for total score 1-0, 3>2 means array list 1 gets a point for total score 2-0, and 4>3 means array list 1 gets a point for total score 3-0. It's then supposed to create a new array list of length 2 and set the first index to 3, the score of the first array list, then set the second index to 0, the score of the second array list.

For some reason I'm getting a runtime error and I cannot figure out what it is.

Any help is appreciated, and if someone could explain what a runtime error is in laymen's terms that would be much appreciated.

```
static List<Integer> compareTriplets(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
        int bobscore = 0;
        int alicescore = 0;
        int throwaway = 0;
        
    
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i ++){
            if (a.get(i) == b.get(i)){
                throwaway++;
            }       
            
            if (a.get(i) > b.get(i)){
                alicescore++;
            }       
            if (a.get(i) < b.get(i)){
                bobscore++;
            }       
            
        }
        
        List<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<>(2);
        scores.set(0, alicescore);
        scores.set(1, bobscore);
        return scores;
    }
```

Comment: first glance: you are assuming that the arraylists are of the same size, and that they are not null. maybe check the size before you start doing anything to them?

Comment: and a runtime error is an error that couldn't be detected at compile time. in other words, "something the compiler didn't foresee happened", for example an empty list, where you expected a list of length 3

Comment: the ArrayList constructor with an int is only for setting the capacity, not the size. Just use `add` instead of `set`. Also, that `throwaway` variable and the if statement that increments it are unused.

Comment: Yup.  You can't `set` values that haven't been added to the list yet.  Use `add`, not `set`.

Comment: For future reference, if you want help on Stack Overflow with any kind of error, it's best to include the error itself in the question.  That way, it's easier for people who want to help you to work out what you've done wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It's this part:

```
List<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<>(2);
        scores.set(0, alicescore);
        scores.set(1, bobscore);
```

That constructor still makes **an empty list**, so `scores.set(0` fails because there is no 1st element to set. The '2' is a 'capacity hint': It is conveying to the arraylist constructor that it should start off by having room for 2 elements.

ArrayLists automatically resize themselves if you keep adding elements to them; however, such a resize does involve an under-the-hood copy of an array, and conversely, arraylists (usually) have more room than you're using, which is fine as well, but in rare circumstances, you want to optimize this; if you know beforehand how large it's gonna be, you can pass that in and the arraylist will be almost inperceptibly faster.

That's why that constructor exists. You should not be using it here.

Most likely you want:

```
List<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<>();
scores.add(aliceScore);
scores.add(bobScore);
```

or even:

```
int[] scores = new int[2];
scores[0] = aliceScore;
scores[1] = bobScore;
```

Note that arraylist and arrays are completely different beasts. ArrayLists start out empty and can grow. arrays have a set size that you must provide upon creation and can never be any smaller or any larger; a `new int[2]` is size 2. And will always be. (The name 'ArrayList' refers to the notion that it uses arrays internally to do its work).

Answer (score 0):

Use the simple static function `List.of(aliceScore, bobScore)` or `Arrays.asList(aliceScore, bobScore)` to return the list result.